# dll has no valid clr header and cannot be disassembled

Tags: dll

While opening a DLL in ILDASM, I am getting an error msg telling the dll has no valid clr header and cannot be disassembled.None of the dll's are getting opened. I am using vs2010 ultimate version. Can any1 help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't disassemble native dll's with ILDASM.

Comment: how can we disassemble it them?